# Problems updating users profile pictures in sharepoint 2013

Tags: mysite, picture

Can someone help me ? I want to manually upload the profile pictures for all my (mysites) sharepoint 2013 users but something awkward is happening.

whenever I update a profile picture every picture inherits the last picture uploaded.

Then I realized the what is happening is the  Profile Picture (Shared) Library is saving the picture with the name of my logged in account, I tried to upload using a service account (on Central Administration) and the same problem occurs.

I am desperate, since we need our company of more then a 800 users to have their pictures uploaded I don't see how can we do it otherwise. Our Active Directory Team is not going to upload the pictures, We have to do it in SharePoint 2013 without  counting on AD.

Can someone help us please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually upload the pictures, the first thing you have to do is block the user rights to upload the profile pictures by them self:

#### From CA >> navigate  _layouts/15/MgrProperty.aspx >> Picture >> Edit Settings >> "**Do not allow user to edit....**"

When this is done basically you must copy the files to this url :**http://mysiteurl/user%20photos**.

Since you have not specify your share point configuration I found this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/briangre/2014/03/11/options-for-sharepoint-user-profile-properties-and-photos/) that cover almost all the possible scenarios.

Remember that for each account it must be created 3 different pictures with the user account login, (format username_LThumb,username_MThumb, username_SThumb) and files must respect certain criteria in their dimensions, the blog include a table.

I'd recommended to you create at least a script or a C# console applications to handle the files importing and pictures renaming.

Feel free to post more details about your configuration more specific you are more helpful answer you can get.

Comment: Hello LR2007_ITA94

The thing is that I believe that its a SharePoint bug that is making all this problem and I want to know hot to fix it. I checked in some other forums that is a matter of installing updates, so I am going to try to install the SharePoint 2013 August 2016 CU  and see if it fixes, if not I will try your approach.

Thank you very much, I will get back to you.